# Cannot get element value even though it it exists on page

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, download, rapidshare

I am working on a javascript downloader and need to click a button. I can see the button and get it's values with web developer and dom inspector in FF. But when I try to:

```
var freeUserForm = this.iFrame.contentDocument.getElementById('js_free-download_btn');
```

It returns null and when I view the page source the element is not there. So what's going on?

Thank you very much,
Todd

Comment: We'll need to see the rest of the code to be sure that your id's and component hierarchy is correct.

Comment: The way that the `this` keyword works in JavaScript is a little weird. Maybe add a trace statement to make sure that it's referring to the object you think it's referring to.

Comment: I turns out the page was loading 3 pages via refreshes and when I was trying to get the element the third DOM had not loaded yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(assuming that the ID of the IFRAME element is "foo")

```
var iframe = document.getElementById("foo");
var freeUserForm = iframe.contentDocument.getElementById("js_free-download_btn");
```